# What does "[Charges not specific to a project]" means?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

A few weeks ago, I signed up my first Google Cloud account. This cloud provider provide 90 day free trial with $300 free credit. I created my first cloud project (My First Project) , used VMs and create Domain name with Cloud Domain.

Today, I opened [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EREwm.jpg) page, for checking Bill report. I was curious what does ["[Charges not specific to a project]"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwCqQ.jpg) mean?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's because some costs like `Support costs` are not related to a project. More info on billing costs can be found in the official docs: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports